# Error when inserting DateTime objects with C# code into Access Database 2016

Tags: c#, jet

I am trying to insert some calendar dates into an Access database using C#. Unfortunately, it is not working for some reason. The problem is the code is running absolutely perfectly on the computers found in my high school, which are running Office 2007, Windows 7. When I run the same code on my Windows 10 laptop, I get the error:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression.'

However, the calendar dates are set in the short format, in the database.

I have already tried to convert the strings I am attempting to insert into the database. Some of the conversions I have tried are:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(itemi[1]);

DateTime.Parse(itemi[2]);

DateTime.ParseExact(itemi[2], "d", null);
```

Where `itemi[2]` is one of the strings which are written in calendar date format.

For example: `itemi[2] = "02.05.2017";` or `itemi[2] = "05.08.2019";`

I have also tried to change the `.` characters found in the `itemi[2]` string with `/` characters, with no success. I have even tried to use the `Trim()` function, in order to make sure the string does not have any blank spaces in it. My professor could not find any solution for this issue, as well, and we looked over the code for hours and searched the internet with no result.

Here is the code with the described issue (the connection to the database has already been opened a few lines of code before, but I consider this to be irrelevant, so I do not include it in the mentioned code):

```
var query = "INSERT INTO Planificari (Frecventa, DataStart, DataStop, IDLocalitate) " 
          + "VALUES ('" + itemi[1].Trim() + "', '" + itemi[2].Trim() 
          + "', '" + itemi[3].Trim() +"', " + idLocalitate + ")";

OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // this is the point I get the mentioned error
                           // DataStart and DataStop are the calendar dates 
                           // in my access 2016 database
```

Comment: A quick fix/check would be to make sure regional settings are the same on your machine and your schools. The correct way to do this sort of thing, however, is to use Database Parameters and that will save you a lot of trouble further down the line

Comment: What "regional settings" means?

Comment: Assuming you are using Windows. From your Start Menu, open Control Panel and double-click on the *Region* (This can be called something similar but different depending on your version) option. This will open up the Regional Settings.